# GCC attribute __attribute__ ((constructor)) from main executable runs after linked libraries constructors

Tags: c, gcc, constructor, gcc-attribute

I noticed that constructors from shared objects linked into my applications will always run before my application constructors, even if my applications has lower priority number (ie: higher priority); for example, let's say this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void __attribute__ ((constructor (101))) test() {
    printf("test\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

is linking the following shared object:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void __attribute__ ((constructor (102))) test_so() {
    printf("test so\n");
}
```

I expected the output to be:

> test
> test so

Instead, the output is the opposite.
Is there any reason why? I could not find any documentation.

Comment: What OS and linker?

Comment: If I had a guess it would be C++, because it's valid to call static objects in a shared library in the `main` function or in a static constructor in the main program. So those constructors would have to run prior to the ones in the main program.

Comment: Priorities of this attribute only matter for the same program (.so in the fact is a separate program) and are not related between different units.

Comment: @NateEldredge it is an GCC extension

Comment: > Priorities of this attribute only matter for the same program (.so in the fact is a separate program) and are not related between different units.  


That's interesting; can you point me to a documentation about this? Or is this something obvious but not stated anywhere?

Comment: @NateEldredge archlinux, glibc 2.33-5 and gcc version 11.1.0 (GCC)

Comment: `can you point me to a documentation about this?` It's not like in open-source projects everything is documented, especially about extensions. Source code _is_ documentation. Here I think: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/elf/dl-init.c#L109

Comment: @Federico see how it works (debugging the startup code **before**). See how so libraries are initialized. It is not C standard.

Comment: @KamilCuk wow thank you very much! That seems to be the actual documentation for the behavior!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any reason why?

Facts:

- `__attribute__((__constructor__))` basically adds a pointer to the function to some ELF section
- Every ELF file has a separate DT_INIT or DT_INIT_ARRAY sections.
- Every ELF file is loaded in order, and dependencies are loaded before executable.
- So shared libraries constructors will run before executable.
- The ordering of `__attribute__((__constructor__(this_number)))` is limited to one ELF file, as compiler can reorder them there.

> could not find any documentation.

It is documented in https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/elf.pdf :

> Initialization and Termination Functions
>
> After the dynamic linker has built the process image and performed the relocations, each shared
> object gets the opportunity to execute some initialization code. All shared object initializations  happen before the executable file gains control.

Comment: The generic (draft) SysV spec can be found at http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch5.dynamic.html#init_fini  NB (again): "All shared object initializations happen before the executable file gains control."