# Segmentation fault without even running the first line of code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, posix, shared-memory

As you can see in the code I've added `printf`s everywhere for debugging and have numbered them. I have tried both repl.it and GCC(on gcc it even compiles and everything but when run, it prints the statement that asks for a user input and scans then fails) on ubuntu but both Show segmentation fault without even printing the first `printf` which is a "1". the code initializes an array in a parent function, sends the array to a child function, then the child prints it. I have to calculate the sum of all the elements in the mentioned array, send it back to the parent, and let the p print it too, but can't even do that if I can't check the functionality of this code
any thoughts?

```
#include <fcntl.h>              
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
    printf("\n1\n");
    int size;
    sem_t *sem1, *sem2, *sem3;
    mode_t perms = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR; 
    int shmflags = O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK;
    int semflags = O_CREAT | O_EXCL;
    srand(time(NULL));
    sem_t *sem = sem_open("/sem1", semflags, perms, 1);
    if (sem == SEM_FAILED) {
        printf("semaphore_open error \n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    printf("\n2\n");
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid > 0) {//parent
        printf("enter the size of array\n");
        scanf("%d", &size);
        int array[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            array[i] = rand() % 1001;
        }
        char str[512];
        int i = 0;
        int index = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            index += sprintf(&str[index], "%d,", array[i]);
        }
        printf("\n3\n");
        size_t len = strlen(str);
        int fd = shm_open("/shmem", shmflags, perms);  
        if (fd == -1) {
            printf("shm_open error \n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        if (ftruncate(fd, len) == -1) {      
            printf("ftruncate error \n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        char *addr = mmap(NULL, len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
        if (addr == MAP_FAILED) {
            printf("mmap error \n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        } 
        if (close(fd) == -1) {                   
            printf("fd close error \n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);    
        }
        sem_wait(sem);
        memcpy(addr, str, strlen(str));
        sem_post(sem);
        wait(NULL);
    } else {  //child
        struct stat sb;
        printf("\n4\n");
        int fd = shm_open("/shmem", O_RDONLY, 0);
        if (fstat(fd, &sb) == -1) {
            printf("fstat error \n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        char *addr = mmap(NULL, sb.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
        if (addr == MAP_FAILED) {
            printf("mmap error \n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        if (close(fd) == -1) {                    
            printf("fd close error \n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);    
        }
        printf("\n5\n");
        sem_wait(sem);
        puts(addr);
        sem_post(sem);
        if (shm_unlink("/shmem") == -1) {                    
            printf("unlink error \n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);    
        }
        if (sem_unlink("/sem1") == -1) {                    
            printf("unlink error \n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);    
        }  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see a program, but not a clear question. _"any thoughts?"_ - no, that's not it. Please ask a clear question.

Comment: I have just compiled your code and ran it,  there is certainly no problem from the first line on. This is the output I got: `1

2
enter the size of array

4
fstat error` Can I please see what you are compiling your code with?

Comment: @TedLyngmo try running it, it fails with printing the first printf which is the first line of the code

Comment: You should try running it yourself with proper analysing tools. It's going to burn - and it'll show you where

Comment: When you compile this, don't you get warnings?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I do not get warnings when I compile this, can you please elaborate on those proper analyzing tools? are there any websites/programs that help in debugging?

Comment: @Vladouch sir how do i show you  what I'm compiling the code with

Comment: Fwiw, the only warnings I get from this, once the posix-c-source macro is properly defined, are the unused decls of sem1,sem1, and sem3. And like Ted, it most certainly doesn't crash before the first printf.

Comment: @HashemTouqan If you don't get warnings, you've not tried hard enough.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I did get warnings before sir I just kept on trying till they all went away but got to this point where it just doesn't compile the way it should on my virtual machine and I don't know why

Comment: Try to make your question into a [mre] so that we all can dig in and you will have help sooner than you think.

Comment: certainly [no crash](https://godbolt.org/z/13hKWvvze) on `printf("\n1\n");`. Are you sure you're running an executable from a fresh build and not something old/stale/unrelated? I had to link with `-pthread -lrt` before it built.

Comment: You have to really try to make a program crash before reaching the first line of `main`. The easiest way is to declare a huge static array in `main`, e.g. `int array[10000000]`. Another way is to [preload functions that replace library functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203846/preloading-my-library). Another way is to [register a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70190799/gcc-attribute-attribute-constructor). I don't see any of that in your code, but who knows what you aren't telling us.

Comment: Are you redirecting the output? I'm just wondering if a lack of flushing at the line-breaks could be confusing you about where the crash is.

Comment: @yano  @EdmCoff @user3386109 trust me I'm as confused as you guys, I've decided to just finish the assignment code without running because this will take god knows how long to figure out. I've described exactly what I did step by step above. this is the code I used, I compiled using ```gcc parallelHW7.c -o ex7.o -lrt -lpthread``` ,then typed ```./ex7.o```, then the program asks for array size as intended but doesn't print the 1, after entering the number for array size this message appears```Segmentation fault (core dumped)```

Comment: shouldn't matter (I don't think), but drop the `.o` from the executable name. At best that's misleading, as *.o indicate object files, not able to be executed standalone. But now you're saying it's making it to the `scanf` and crashing after entry. That's decidedly far past your `printf`. This might actually be a use case where posting a picture of your terminal is useful, not sure I believe you that it's not printing ;). Make it `printf("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n");` or something easier to see.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few good candidates for undefined behavior:

```
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int array[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = rand() % 1001;
    }
```

If `size` is too large, say greater than a few millions, the array allocated with automatic storage will likely cause a **stack overflow**.

```
    char str[512];
    int i = 0;
    int index = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        index += sprintf(&str[index], "%d,", array[i]);
    }
```

If `size` entered by the user is larger than 128, the code converting the array to a string will likely cause a buffer overflow causing undefined behavior.

In the child process:

```
    puts(addr);
```

`addr` points to the memory mapped file contents. This file does not contain a null terminator, hence if by chance its size is a multiple of the page size, the memory mapped block will not contain a null terminator and `puts(addr)` will read beyond the end of the block, causing undefined behavior.

Note that none of the above may cause the process to fail before the first `printf` call.